# how to hide the content in DRUPAL to display front.......?

Tags: php, drupal

i wanted a module in drupal where my user or admin can have option for display the content where ever her wants [admin should have an option to display the content in latest news or upcomming news or the content, the content should not repeat in other categories].. which publishing the content in drupal the admin should have the option for all the option...

Answer (score 1):

What about the checkbox "Promoted to front page" in the node forms ? Is not that enough?

Comment: im working on a project were the old developer removed that option [Promoted to front page] and now im not getting it. i need option were i can have option where "publish" [will publish the page but not on front page], "publish to front page" [publish on front page n also  to other page], "publish to upcomming events" [will publish only in upcomming events]... plzzzz help me...

Comment: Sorry, when is a code-customized Drupal installation, how can I help you?